# I dismissed "For You" in iTunes 12.2 for Mac, How do I get it back?

Tags: itunes, mac, apple-music

## Context

OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
iTunes 12.2.0.145

## Question

**I just installed iTunes 12.2 for OS X, the first version of iTunes with new Apple Music features.**

After installing (which went perfectly smoothly AFAICT), I launched the new iTunes (with the new white icon). There was a new tab in the top center called `For You`. I clicked on this tab, and was shown a screen with a lot of exciting `For You` content. Then I clicked a text link on this page that said `Go to My Music`.

I was taken back to the `My Music` tab, and the `For You` tab disappeared entirely. I didn't expect that `For You` would completely disappear if I clicked that text link. I'd like to get the `For You` tab back.

I've searched thru the iTunes main menu, and thru the iTunes (modal) Preferences window, and thru my iTunes Account Info page in vain. I cannot find any way to reinstate the `For You` tab. How can I get the `For You` tab back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP Here. I found two ways to reinstate the `For You` tab.

1. There is also a setting for this in the iTunes Preferences Window after all:

   `Preferences > General > Show Apple Music`

[image]

2. Alternatively, in the main menu, click `Account > Apple Music…`. This will make the `For You` tab and another `New` tab return. Although the content under the `For You` tab is now gone, and in its place there's just a button for trying Apple Music and another for `Go to my Music`.

Answer (score 5):

- In the **View** menu, select Music (⌘1)
- If you don't see words like "My Music, Playlists, **For You**, New, Radio, Connect..." then continue.
- In the **Account** menu, select Sign Out
- Then sign back in and repeat the first step ⌘1

---

The For You tab is generated by Apple's servers, so any busy-ness there or overload can cause it to be blank. You might also need to go through the steps to identify which genres and then artists you like and which ones you love a second time if your initial elections didn't get saved properly to the cloud.

Worst case - check Apple's System Status page - http://apple.com/support/systemstatus and consider reaching out to Apple Support if your account doesn't clear itself out over an 8 hour period or more.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Merely clicking this menu item (`Main Menu > Account > Apple Music…`) made the `For You` tab and another `New` tab return. Although the content under the `For You` tab is now gone, and in its place there's just a button for trying Apple Music and another for `Go to my Music`.

Comment: I had to sign out first to get the menu item to appear.